# how to configure quartz in netbeans

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, netbeans6.7

I have downloaded quartz scheduler.I wrote a program for generating random numbers for every 2 mins.I want to configure this program with quartz scheduler.I searched through the net but  i am unclear with this.could anyone tel the steps to configure quartz with my program and how to use it.I want to run this in netbeans ide.All your views are appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly short [outline](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/) at IBM developerWorks.

Example 2 "Simple Triggers" would be a good starting point for your regularly repeating job.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Quartz in conjunction with Spring (documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz)).  This allows you to define your Quartz jobs in Spring config (i.e. XML) rather than hard-coding them into your project.